# CakePHP 2.4.4 Unable to sort/order by virtual field with paginate (Paginator)

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, virtual

My Virtual Field for Property model, generated in beforeFind(), called 'distance', works. However, I can't sort by it. I currently have this as part of the search form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('sort', array(
    'options' => Hash::get($predefined, 'sort'), // List of options
));
```

Which adds sort to the URL, and it works for all normal fields, but not the virtual field distance. Should I have implemented this differently? As far as I'm aware, Virtual Fields should work fine with pagination.

EDIT: In case I've implemented pagination wrong...

I've set defaults:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => array(
       'Properties.id' => 'asc'
    )
);
```

After building $conditions:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Property', $conditions);
$this->set('properties', $data);
```

The above works fine changing the order, even by directly editing /sort:fieldname/ in the URL, but not with the virtual field 'distance'. I also tried adding, without success:

```
$this->paginate['order'] = array($value); //Value is the value for 'sort' named parameter
```

Comment: "Since virtual fields behave much like regular fields when doing find’s, Controller::paginate() will be able to sort by virtual fields too."  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Comment: Try to use third parameter (whitelist) for paginate (http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-PaginatorComponent.html#116-248).
If it won't help put more code (beforeFilter method and more of controllers method).

Comment: That's not relevant to the question, but it is useful, thanks, I'll implement with that from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your message:

> My Virtual Field for Property model, generated in beforeFind(),

Seems to be the issue.

The virtual field needs to be defined before your call to Paginate() so that the paginator knows to build the "sort" criteria.

The `beforeFind()` call happens *after* the pagination call, so your virtual field is not yet defined. Moving the definition of the virtual field right above the the pagination call should fix this.

Comment: Virtual fields can be declared in the model as a an array, public $virtualFields = array(); , or elsewhere, with $this->virtualFields['fieldName'] = , which allows you to create the field only when needed. Doing so in beforeFind puts it ahead of any sql, so it should behave exactly the same

Comment: Try searching "Virtual Fields on the fly"

Comment: I cannot find that. It still looks to me though, that your virtual field is not actually defined when the pagination tries to figure out the sorting order. And think that happens before the call to `beforeFind()`. So I would try to define that in the model as opposed to on the fly. Or if you do it on the fly, define it just before the call to Paginate() instead of beforeFind()

Comment: It's nearer the bottom the the Virtual Fields page. The user must enter 'postcode' in a search form first, otherwise there'd be no distance to calculate, so this must be checked before making the field. I'll try adding it via the controller before Paginate runs

Comment: That's solved it! You're right about the order of events, the field had to exist before paginate, as beforeFind would be within paginate. If you'd like to edit your answer to include your suggest I can accept it