# Cake PHP : Warning (2): vsprintf() [function.vsprintf]: Too few arguments [CORE\Cake\basics.php, line 562]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I'm upgrading a CakePHP application from version 1.3 to version 2.4.6 .I have copied all of my Model, View and Controller maintaining Cake Naming Conventions.The Application is running but showing these Notice And Warning..

#### Warnings :

> Warning (2): vsprintf() [function.vsprintf]: Too few arguments [CORE\Cake\basics.php, line 562]

#### Notice:

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property ProspectsController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\ProspectsController.php, line 51]
>
> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property ProspectsController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\ProspectsController.php, line 52]

Strict (2048): Declaration of Segment::beforeSave() should be compatible with Model::beforeSave($options = Array) [APP\Model\Segment.php, line 41]

> #### And Whats wrong with this pagination style ?
>
> [image]

Showing These Notice...

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property ProspectsController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\ProspectsController.php, line 51]

Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property ProspectsController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\ProspectsController.php, line 52]

> Now what can I do to remove these warnings and Notice ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484145/cakephp-2-4-4-unable-to-sort-order-by-virtual-field-with-paginate-paginator

Comment: For the $paginate notice see [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/01/22/cakephp-tips/)